# multiple Case statement in a query

Tags: teradata

Can you please tell me why this statement is wrong, it is giving me an error that it was expecting something else instead of the case phrase

```
      SELECT  ACT.Employee_Id, 
      case  when max( case when not ACT.ActivityTime_Date like '2019-09-%' and ACT.Activity_Time_Date not like '09/%/2019' and 
      not (ACT.Action like 'ACTIVITY_create_%' or ACT.Action like 'ACTIVITY_update_%') and
       not ACT.Destination_ObjectType in ('announcement', 'attachment'
      ,'blog','blogpost','community', 'directmessage', 'document', 'event', 'idea', 'message', 'poll', 'project', 'question',
      'socialgroup', 'task', 'thread', 'video', 'wallentry')) then 1 else 0 
      END)=0
      then 'Contributor'
       from Analytics.ConnectTodayActive ACT;
```

This is the error

```
SQL Editor 1: Encountered "case when max ( case when not ( ACT . ActivityTime_Date like \'2019-09-%\' or ACT . ActivityTime_Date like \'09/%/2019\' ) and not ( ACT . Action like not.
Was expecting one of:
    "column" ...
    "row" ...
    "transactiontime" ...
    "validtime" ...
    "(" ...
    "until_changed" ...
    "until_closed" ...
    <NAME> ...
    "sampleid" ...
    "interval" ...
    "date" ...
    "time" ...
    "timestamp" ...
    "begin" ...
    "end" ...
    "next" ...
    <SINGLE_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    ":" ...
    "?" ...
    <NAMED_QUESTIONMARK> ...
    "@" ...
    "null" ...
    "user" ...
    "current_role" ...
    "current_user" ...
    "session" ...
    "account" ...
    "database" ...
    "role" ...
    "profile" ...
    "zone" ...
    "td_host" ...
    "td_authid" ...
    "new" ...
    "current_date" ...
```

Comment: [edit] your question to `>quote` the error in full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't seem to be formatted correctly:

- your outer `CASE` statement is missing an `END`
- an end parenthesis is out of place
- if you want to return `employee_id`, you need to use a `GROUP BY` since you're using `MAX`

You should be able to combine your `LIKE` conditions too, so something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  ACT.Employee_Id, 
  CASE 
    WHEN MAX (
      CASE 
        WHEN 
          ACT.ActivityTime_Date NOT LIKE ALL('2019-09-%','09/%/2019') AND
          ACT.Action NOT LIKE ALL ('ACTIVITY_create_%','ACTIVITY_update_%') AND
          ACT.Destination_ObjectType NOT IN ('announcement','attachment','blog','blogpost','community', 'directmessage', 'document', 'event','idea', 'message', 'poll', 'project', 'question', 'socialgroup', 'task', 'thread', 'video', 'wallentry')
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END
    ) = 0 THEN 'Contributor'
  END AS my_col
FROM Analytics.ConnectTodayActive ACT
GROUP BY ACT.Employee_Id;
```

[SQL Fiddle (Postgres)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8cf02/2)